# Extracting a line identified by special character '*' and storing it in a variable

Tags: bash, grep, special-characters

On Lubuntu 16.02, this command shows information about all desktops:

```
$ wmctrl -d
0  - DG: 3926x1600  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,24 2560x1576  desktop 1
1  - DG: 3926x1600  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,24 2560x1576  desktop 2
2  * DG: 3926x1600  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,24 2560x1576  desktop 3
3  - DG: 3926x1600  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,24 2560x1576  desktop 4
4  - DG: 3926x1600  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,24 2560x1576  desktop 5
```

Need to store and process the information about the active desktop, what shows up by:

```
$ wmctrl -d | grep "*"
2  * DG: 3926x1600  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,24 2560x1576  desktop 3
```

For some strange reason, this solution won't store the information needed:

```
$ activedesktop=$(wmctrl -d | grep "*")
$ echo $activedesktop
2 Desktop Documents Downloads Mail Music Pictures Public Videos DG: 3926x1600 VP: 0,0 WA: 0,24 2560x1576 desktop 3
```

As the variable inserts the home directories names where the "*" was supposed to be.

Why is this happening, and how to solve it?

Comment: Escape the `*`. Or use `grep "[*]"`. Also, see [matching a line with a literal asterisk “*” in grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581307/matching-a-line-with-a-literal-asterisk-in-grep)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `activedesktop=$(wmctrl -d | grep "\*")` and `activedesktop=$(wmctrl -d | grep "[*]")` raise the same (wrong) result...

Comment: Try `echo "$activedesktop"`.

Comment: @melpomene gosh! I see it was replacing the asterisk in the second place...

Comment: Not the cause, but I recommend `fgrep` (or GNU `grep -F`) to match a fixed pattern instead of regexp.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @melpomene, the variable does store the information needed, but the former `echo` interprets the asterisk.

So, the solution is just to double-quote the variable as in `echo "$activedesktop"`.